# How do I call a Commandlet dynamically using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use a commandlet (I'm using [NavContainerHelper](https://github.com/Microsoft/navcontainerhelper)) dynamically.

My parameters are in a `System.Collections.Generic.List` with the type `string`:

```
$navContainerHelperParameters = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[string]'
$navContainerHelperParameters.Add("-accept_eula")
```

I already tried using the @ before the call of the commandlet: `New-NavContainer @navContainerHelperParameters`, but this did not work as expected.

What would be the best way to call a commandlet dynamically?

Comment: Take a look at `Invoke-Command` and the `-Argumentlist` option.

Comment: I don't think that Invoke-Command would help me with my problem. It seems that it would only be good if I'm using something like `-containerName $containerName` and `$containerName` is out of scope

Comment: Perhaps it's just me but I fail to see anything dynamic about calling a cmdlet with one switch parameter. Just run `New-NavContainer -accept_eula`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers that's just an example. In my script I have more parameters that are dynamically added

Comment: Next time please choose an example that actually demonstrates the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use splatting, which requires the parameters to be set in a hashtable and then passed with @ infront of the variable name to the cmdlet. You can set the switch parameter by setting the value to $true.

```
$navContainerHelperParameters = @{}
[void]$navContainerHelperParameters.Add("accept_eula",$true)
New-NavContainer @navContainerHelperParameters
```